# How should i do to convert binary or integer to heximal in VHDL

Tags: binary, integer, hex, vhdl

I have binary value as input and I need to convert it to hexadecimal output. How should I do this?

I'm new in here. Please advise to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your signal is a multiple of 4-bits, then you can use X to indicate hex.

```
signal d : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := X"1234";
```

If your signal is a mixture, you can use a concatenate operator, eg., to set 18-bits to 0x12345, you could use

```
signal d : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0) := "01" & X"2345";
```

Using VHDL-2008 you can use a width specifier

```
signal d : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0) := 18X"12345";
```

You can also use conversion functions, e.g., to convert an integer value in hex format 16#12345# to std_logic_vector.

Comment: sorry, If binary input have 12bit and it can changes all time  then i can't use it in " " . how i should to do